# While loop Int return inside the method completely dead

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, int

My task is to write a method:

```
public static int collectInteger(String prompt, int minimum, int maximum)
```

where in `while` loop user's input is collected, and processed as follows bellow (#1) but of course it doesn't work since it cannot read inputs from method... this is actually what my prof suggested... simple stuff is easy in methods, but it doesn't make sense to do while loop in method and then redo the whole bloody thing again in main. 
I rewrote it with booleans in method - works fine.. wrote it without method - also works of course. But I cannot put my head around this while loop and int method...
This is our second day working with methods and homework is nothing like class work..
Thank you for your suggestions!

```
// #1 this is what prof suggested...

public static int collectInteger(String prompt, int minimum, int maximum){
        // make sure that the value is an int
        while (true) {
              if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                     int value = in.nextInt();
                     if (value >= minimum && value <= maximum){
                            return value;
                     }
              } else {
                     System.out.println("Error Message");
              }
        }
}
//#2 this is what I could come up with that doesn't work of course...

public static int collectInteger(int minimum, int maximum){
        while (true){
            if (value >= minimum && value <= maximum){
                return value;       
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            final int MINIMUM =0, MAXIMUM =100;

            System.out.print("Enter a number of cats. ");
            int catsNumber = in.nextInt(); 
            int catsInput =  collectInteger (MINIMUM, MAXIMUM);
            if (catsNumber == catsInput){
                System.out.printf("Your number of cats was %d", catsNumber);
                in.hasNextInt();
            }else {
                System.out.println("Value needs to be an integer between 0 and 100. Please try again.");
            }
            in.close();     
        }
    }
```

// result should be simple... if input is btw `0` and `100`, print number of input cats, if not - print error message. But min and max value should be written in method first...

Comment: Where does this variable `value` come from? Is it a class field?

Comment: Try debug and step through, and you'll find there is an infinite loop in your method `collectInteger()`

Comment: Unclear: your task is to write the method, but the teacher gave you the code of the method to write. So your job is done regarding this method, right? Just take what the teacher suggested. What's the problem with the method that your teacher gave you? Why do you think a method can't read inputs?

Comment: @Thibstars pretty much nowhere )). It got converted to static as it was giving an error. "value" supposedly an input from the user and it should be an int. I tried just adding it as a local variable, but of course that is not the way to do so and I don't know how else...

Comment: @JBNizet it doesn't work... I tried. main doesn't read it

Comment: Where do you define the variable `value`?

Comment: @Alex it's defined in private static

Comment: @Rish the code you posted doesn't use the method that the teacher gave you. So, try using it (and realize you need to define a static field named `in` containing the scanner before calling it), and if it still "doesn't work", then edit your question, post the code, and tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Not just "it doesn't work". Read and post any error you might get.

Comment: There are issues in the method the professor gave you. It has some variables like the Scanner `in` which is not defined in the method. Also a method which is declared to return an `int` need to return an `int` or throw and Exception. The compiler should warn you about this. Since you say you have just started with methods, Exceptions are probably overkill. Just return -1 or something in that case.

Comment: @patrik thanks! I have modified a little... it still gives bugs... will work some more on it. in non integer - it gives an infinite loop of error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I changed some of your code and added another system to check continue or exit. This works:

```java
public static boolean CheckcollectInteger(int inputValue,int minimum, int maximum){
            if (inputValue >= minimum && inputValue <= maximum){
                return true;       
            }else {
                return false;
            }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            final int MINIMUM =0, MAXIMUM =100;

            while(true){
                System.out.print("Enter a number of cats :");
                int catsNumber;
                //check input is integer or not
                try{
                    catsNumber = in.nextInt();
                }catche(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Value needs to be an integer. Try again");
                   continue;
                }
                //check input valie is btw 0-100 or not
                boolean catInputCheck =  CheckcollectInteger(catsNumber,MINIMUM, MAXIMUM);
                if (catInputCheck){
                    System.out.printf("Your number of cats was %d", catsNumber);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Value needs to be an integer between 0 and 100. Please try again.");
                }

                //----check continue or exit system
                System.out.print("Do you want to continue ? (yes / no)");
                String isContinue = in.nextLine();
                if(isContinue.equals("no") || isContinue.equals("NO")){
                    break; //exit loop
                }
            }
            in.close();     
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did however make a good progress converted the program into a boolean method- that was easier for some reason to do so, but I have to try and do it as "int CheckcollectInteger(int inputValue,int minimum, int maximum). I fixed it partially, but I still get a infinite loop when trying to do is a int input and int return. I checked with Pythontutor.com (java) and it gets an error on that checking the int input

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a method that ask a user for an input until it is in a range then the loop should be in the method as your professor has proposed. Otherwise you have one task in this case 'get input from user until it is in correct range" but you separate the logic in different places which makes it harder to follow.

If you notice your professor methods handles both the check for value AND the input. If you have the input in the main method (as you have done it) then in the method you should pass the value you have read from used input (the "value" in your method).

So one solution would be to add the scanner to the method that the professor suggested so you can read the input there:

```
public static int collectInteger(Scanner in, String prompt, int minimum, int maximum){
    // make sure that the value is an int
    while (true) {
          System.out.print(prompt);
          if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                 int value = in.nextInt();
                 if (value >= minimum && value <= maximum){
                        return value;
                 }
          } else {
                 System.out.println("Error Message the value must be between "+ minimum+ " and "+ maximum);
          }
    }
}
```

And when you have that complex logic handled in the method then your main will be as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MINIMUM =0, MAXIMUM =100;
        int catsNumber= collectInteger(in, "Enter a number of cats. ",MINIMUM, MAXIMUM);        
        System.out.printf("Your number of cats was %d", catsNumber);
      in.close();     
    }
```

I would keep the scanner initialization and closing in main because this way the method can work with other input sources - not just the keyboard ;)

Also be careful with these Scanners from System.in because if you close the scanner it also closes the system input stream and later on if you need to read something else it will not work

Comment: I thought the main should be as simple as you put it, but I couldn't come up with "Scanner in" in method on my own because we didn't study it yet :) 
Thank you!

Comment: Read more about scope of variables etc. Or just wait until you study it. But it's the same as for the integers. When you need something in the method you need to pass it (unless it is global for the class)

Comment: right. These past week I spent a lot of time reading through books and websites to understand it )) When I ran this program through the online programming languages tester it gives an error in the method where the program goes through the integer input  check - if (in.hasNextInt()) {... I assume this is why when I run it in eclipse, it is not picking up the error message from the method but rather just looping the "enter number of cats" until I give it a right in range number.